# Add a class to input[text]/ delete previous append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('#learn').append($('input:text').val());
  });
});
```

```css
#one{
  color=red;
}
input{
  color:red;
}
#learn{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type='text' name='name' id='one'><br>
  <button>
    Press
  </button>
  <div>
  <p id='learn'>
    Hi 
  </p>
</div>
```

Two questions:

1. How can I add the class `learn` to the `input[text]` within the
   html?
2. Every time I add something new into the `input [text]` and press the button, it doesn't delete what was appended on the last press. How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.append()`, use `.text()`, which sets a new text to the div and removes the previous text, and add the class to the input by the class attribute `class='learn'` :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('#learn').text("Hi " + $('input:text').val());
  });
});
```

```css
#one{
  color=red;
}
input{
  color:red;
}
#learn{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type='text' name='name' id='one' class='learn'><br>
  <button>
    Press
  </button>
  <div>
  <p id='learn'>
    
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.If you want to add the exact same class as the id of the `<p>` tag use this:

```
$('#one').addClass($('#learn').attr('id'));
```

Otherwise you can just use: `class = "learn"`

2.You can try with `.text()`

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('#learn').text("Hi " + $('input:text').val());
    });
});
```

If you want to keep the "Hi" text but it's too long you can just create a variable which will hold it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var learnText = $('#learn').text();
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('#learn').text(learnText + $('input:text').val());
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rk9fqctL/2/) for 2.